# Configure targetUrlParameter when using Spring Sso Client

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on

I'm looking for a way to redirect to a custom URL after finish Oauth2 login.

After debug my application, i identify that the class `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` do the redirect according some parameters, and that `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.SsoSecurityConfigurer` create and configure the `OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter` that has the successHandler instance.

How can i configure that handler?

My Configuration Class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class AuthClientConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
            .antMatchers("/app/**/*.{js,html}")
            .antMatchers("/i18n/**")
            .antMatchers("/content/**")
            .antMatchers("/static/**")
            .antMatchers("/test/**")
            .antMatchers("/h2-console/**");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .logout().and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/index.html", "/home.html", "/", "/login", "/static/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
            // @formatter:on
    }
}
```